# Mass Alter Stored Procedure to Include New Line of Code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've created a table that can log some details of how often a SP is called, and by who.

I've been able to add some script to the stored procedures which will fire everytime it is called.

However, we have a lot of Stored Procedures which we want to monitor, and they will all need this one line of code adding.

Is there a way to tag this one line of code onto the end of every Stored Procedure, without having to update each one individually?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, don't lose your time asking and just do it... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about generating new `ALTER PROCEDURE` lines using something like the following ?

```
select REPLACE(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEUDRE') 
+ '**YOUR NEW LINE**;' as 'Def' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

A simple example is here:

```
create procedure Hello
as
print 'Hello';
GO

select REPLACE(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE') + ' print ''World'';' as 'Def' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_NAME = 'Hello'

ALTER PROCEDURE Hello
as
print 'Hello';
 print 'World';

exec Hello
```

Comment: Usually a stored procedure ends with an `END` - would your code still work?

Comment: This is a good start.  Im thinking of importing all of the SQL for the procedures into Excel, and then generating a file that I can run to edit them all automatically.

Comment: Many of our SPs look like this: `CREATE PROCEDURE Hello AS BEGIN PRINT 'Hello' END GO`

Comment: So if I wanted to to insert an exec statement immediately after the first "begin" could I use the REPLACE function to replace BEGIN with "BEGIN EXEC.......................... etc"?

Comment: @bushel Yes, I don't see why not.

Comment: @bushel Although `REPLACE` will replace all occurrences of `BEGIN`. There are versions that will replace the first occurrence dotted around the internet.

Comment: @bhs Thank you.  I think if I replaced "as begin" then that should be the first instance.  with a new line return too, so its like this... REPLACE(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 'as' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'begin' ....

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this. You could export all stored procedures as text and then generate a tool in C# for example to add your line, but that's not "pure SQL" as you're asking.